# MySQL Keyword Search Across Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, database, search, keyword, multiple-tables

I have three tables in a MySQL database used in a music library application:

The `Genre` table has columns:

- `id`
- `title` (string)

The `Album` table has columns:

- `id`
- `genre_id` (foreign key to `Genre.id`)
- `title` (string)
- `artist` (string)

and the `Track` table has columns:

- `id`
- `album_id` (foreign key to `Album.id`)
- `title` (string)

Each `Album` can have any number of `Tracks`, each `Track` has one `Album`, and each `Album` has one `Genre`.

---

I want to implement a keyword search that allows the user to input any number of keywords and find all `Tracks` that:

- have a matching `title`,
- are on an `Album` with a matching `title` or `artist`,
- or are on an `Album` with a `Genre` with a matching `title`.

Results should be sorted by relevancy.  It would be great if each field had a ranking for relevancy. For example, the `title` of a `Track` might be more important than the `title` of the `Genre`.

Also, the solution should use some form of partial searching. A search of `rubber` should first match all `Tracks` with a `title` of `Rubber`, then match `Tracks` with a `title` matching `*rubber*` (`*`=wildcard), then move on to `Albums`, and so on. However, I'm not so set on these details. I'm just looking for a more general solution that I can tweak to match my specific needs.

I should also mention that I'm using a LAMP stack, Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

---

**What is the best way to implement this keyword search?**

---

***Update:*** I've been trying to implement this via a full text search, and have come up with the following SQL statements.

```
CREATE TABLE `Genre` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `Genre` VALUES(1, 'Rock');

CREATE TABLE `Album` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `genre_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `artist` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY (`title`, `artist`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `Album` VALUES(1, 1, 'Rubber Soul', 'The Beatles');

CREATE TABLE `Track` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `Track` VALUES(1, 1, 'Drive My Car');
INSERT INTO `Track` VALUES(2, 1, 'What Goes On');
INSERT INTO `Track` VALUES(3, 1, 'Run For Your Life');
INSERT INTO `Track` VALUES(4, 1, 'Girl');
```

Comment: Are you looking for exact matching or partial matching?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've added more info to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).  Use the [Data Import Handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to define an SQL query that joins all your tables together, create a fulltext index from the result of joined data.

---

The columns named as args to MATCH() must be the column(s) you defined for the index, in the same order you defined in the index. But you can't define any index (fulltext or otherwise) across multiple tables in MySQL.

So you can't do this:

```
WHERE MATCH (g.title, a.title, a.artist, t.title) AGAINST ('beatles')
```

It doesn't matter whether you're using boolean mode or natural language mode.

You need to do this:

```
WHERE MATCH (g.title) AGAINST ('beatles')
   OR MATCH (a.title, a.artist) AGAINST ('beatles')
   OR MATCH (t.title) AGAINST ('beatles')
```

---

You may also be interested in my presentation [Practical Full-Text Search in MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

Answer (score 1):

Define a fulltext index on the four columns you like to search and then do:

```
SELECT * FROM genre AS g
  LEFT JOIN album AS a ON g.id = a.genre_id
  LEFT JOIN tracks AS t ON a.id = t.album_id
  WHERE MATCH (g.title,  a.title, a.artist, t.title) AGAINST ('searchstring');
```

The resullt will be sorted by relevancy.
See here for more details on fulltext search:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: Problem is, the OP wants partial matching. Wildcards work but only for characters following the searchstring. You can't apply the wildcard * to the start of the searchstring

Comment: I think the only way of doing an exact match first and then a LIKE * abc * match in MySQL is to use two queries.
The Fulltext solution, I think, is the closest you can get in only one query.

Comment: This works, though it has to be in boolean mode.  My modified query is: `SELECT * FROM Genre AS g LEFT JOIN Album AS a ON g.id = a.genre_id LEFT JOIN Track AS t ON a.id = t.album_id WHERE MATCH (g.title,  a.title, a.artist, t.title) AGAINST ('beatles' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

When I run the query without `IN BOOLEAN MODE`, I get a `#1210 - Incorrect arguments to MATCH` error.

Comment: Yes, got the same error.
It will work without BOOLEAN MODE, if you split the 4 MATCH arguments like this:

SELECT * FROM Genre AS g
  LEFT JOIN Album AS a ON g.id = a.genre_id
  LEFT JOIN Track AS t ON a.id = t.album_id
  WHERE MATCH (g.title) AGAINST ('beatles')
    + MATCH (a.title, a.artist) AGAINST ('beatles')
    + MATCH (t.title) AGAINST ('beatles')

Though I get an empty result then and I can't figgure out why atm.

Comment: You're probably getting an empty result because you're using natural language mode and your search criterion matches >50% of the rows.  Natural language mode won't return rows in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like Sphinx, u can make an index out of your query and then query that.
It's a little difficult to get your head around but the results are 10 times better than mysql AGAINST and you won't have problems later on with speed.